# Unable to change switch state from async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-switch

I need to change the state of the switch from inside an async task. I have set an onClickListner() on the switch in my custom adapter and I am passing its reference to the async task. In my async task I trying to update the state of the switch using publish progress and onProgressUpdate. But the state of the switch is not changing in the UI. Could someone please help me on this?

Below is my code:

DeviceAdapter.java

```
public class DeviceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Device> {

private List<Device> deviceInfo;
private Device device;

private View customView;
private Switch socketSwitch;

private DevicesInfoDbAdapter devicesInfoDbAdapter;

public DeviceAdapter(Context context, List<Device> deviceInfo) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_device_details, deviceInfo);
    this.deviceInfo = deviceInfo;
    device = deviceInfo.get(0);
    devicesInfoDbAdapter = DBFactory.getDevicesInfoDbAdapter(getContext());
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_device_details, parent, false);
    socketSwitch = (Switch) customView.findViewById(R.id.socketSwitch);
    ImageButton btnRefresh = (ImageButton) customView.findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);


    btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("socketswitch1",""+socketSwitch);
            DeviceStatusRefreshAsync deviceStatusRefreshAsync = new DeviceStatusRefreshAsync(socketSwitch);
            deviceStatusRefreshAsync.execute();
        }
    });

    return customView;
}


}
```

DeviceStatusRefreshAsync.java

```
public class DeviceStatusRefreshAsync extends AsyncTask {

    private Switch socketSwitch;

    public DeviceStatusRefreshAsync(Switch socketSwitch) {
        this.socketSwitch = socketSwitch;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {

        publishProgress();  //Calling to update the switch state

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(Object[] values) {

        socketSwitch.setChecked(true);   //Switch state not changing in the UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe yo should call invalidate ?

Comment: Just update deviceInfo list on click of btnRefresh.

Comment: socketSwitch  is always the one from last getView call ... you need to fix it: final inside right scope or get/setTag ... of course it will be useless unless you do not save the state somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using OnClickListener use **OnCheckedChangeListener** and instead of using onProgressUpdate use **onPostExecute** for change the state of switch.

Comment: yes we will do UI related operation in onPostExecute() of AsyncTask.

Comment: @hitesh141 : Please tick my answer if you agree with it.

Comment: @SundeepBadhotiya: The OnCheckedChangeListner method is not present for view. May be I am getting something wrong.

Comment: socketSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked)
    {
     // do your code here
    }
    else
    {
     // do your code here
    }
    
   }

Comment: But why are you setting listener on switch? Shouldn't it be on the refresh button? I need to change the state of the "switch" on click of the refresh button.

Comment: Use onPostExecute method  of AsynTask for any change on UI